# Using props data for a select field

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, next.js

I'm fetching data in `index.tsx` which I later on pass to `FormOne` just as following and I'm then able to use the data in FormOne using `props.data`

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

...

return (
    ...
    <FormOne data={data} />
);
```

I want to replace "Pick a user" in `FormOne` with a list of the users from `props.data`. The idea is to select a user a query e.g. "What address does he have?", which leads to user's email address being printed right below the form, not sure how to do that either. How can I achieve that?

```
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  FormControl,
  Grid,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
  SelectChangeEvent,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import { useState } from 'react';

const FormOne = (props: any) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('');
  const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setUser(event.target.value);
    setQuery(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h4" align="center">
        GUI #1
      </Typography>

      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Pick a user</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              value={user}
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              <MenuItem value={10}>User 1</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={20}>User 2</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={30}>User 3</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
            <InputLabel id="demo-simple-select-label">Query</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="demo-simple-select-label"
              id="demo-simple-select"
              value={query}
              onChange={handleChange}
            >
              <MenuItem value={10}>What email does he use?</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={20}>What address does he have?</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Button variant="contained">Submit</Button>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default FormOne;
```

### [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-roentgen-6915nx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  FormControl,
  Grid,
  InputLabel,
  MenuItem,
  Select,
  SelectChangeEvent,
  Typography,
} from '@mui/material';
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  address: {
    street: string;
    suite: string;
    city: string;
    zipcode: string;
    geo: {
      lat: string;
      lng: string;
    };
  };
  phone: string;
  website: string;
  company: {
    name: string;
    catchPhrase: string;
    bs: string;
  };
}

const FormOne = (props: any) => {
  const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState<User | null>(null);
  const [selectedQuery, setSelectedQuery] = useState<number>(1);

  // both handle change functions must be seperate
  const handleQueryChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    setSelectedQuery(Number(event.target.value));
  };

  const handleUserChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    // since select menu item accepts string number or string[] values we put id as the value but in state we can filter the user out like this
    const user = props.data.find(
      (user: User) => user.id === Number(event.target.value)
    );
    setSelectedUser(user);
  };

  return (
    <Box component="form" noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <Typography component="h1" variant="h4" align="center">
        GUI #1
      </Typography>

      <Grid container spacing={2}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
            <InputLabel id="user-label">Pick a user</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="user-label"
              id="user"
              value={selectedUser?.id?.toString()}
              onChange={handleUserChange}
            >
              {/*  you can map users using javascript map function */}
              {props.data.map((user: User) => {
                return (
                  <MenuItem key={user.id} value={user.id.toString()}>
                    {user.email}
                  </MenuItem>
                );
              })}
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <FormControl variant="outlined" fullWidth>
            <InputLabel id="query-label">Query</InputLabel>
            <Select
              labelId="query-label"
              id="query"
              value={selectedQuery.toString()}
              onChange={handleQueryChange}
            >
              <MenuItem value={1}>What email does he use?</MenuItem>
              <MenuItem value={2}>What address does he have?</MenuItem>
            </Select>
          </FormControl>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Button variant="contained">Submit</Button>
        </Grid>

        <Grid item xs={12}>
          {selectedUser && selectedQuery === 1 && (
            <p>user email : {`${selectedUser?.email}`}</p>
          )}
          {selectedUser && selectedQuery === 2 && (
            <p>
              user address : {selectedUser?.address?.street}
              {selectedUser?.address?.city}
            </p>
          )}
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </Box>
  );
};

export default FormOne;
```

So basically, you needed to map props in order to get `menuItems` rendered.
And, in order to show user data, you have to show it like I have done in my code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I did what you said, but it doesn't print any email for the selected user. `MUI: You have provided an out-of-range value `undefined` for the select component.
Consider providing a value that matches one of the available options or ''.
The available values are `1`, `2`. 
SelectInput@webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@mui/material/Select/SelectInput.js:164:7`. Btw, I updated the CodeSandbox, you can see the changes

Comment: This is `FormOne.tsx`'s code if you feel it's easier than looking at the CodeSandbox: https://pastebin.com/MHc2pUBx

Comment: I have changed my answer and it works fine now. the mistake in the earlier code was that I was using filter instead of find.

Comment: Thank you very much! Is it possible to make the printing part only when the "Submit" button is pressed?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me like you want to dynamically render MenuItem components, in order to archive that you should replace your hardcoded

```
<MenuItem value={10}>User 1</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={20}>User 2</MenuItem>
<MenuItem value={30}>User 3</MenuItem>
```

with something like this:

```
{props.data.map((item, index) => {
    return <MenuItem key={index} value={item}>{item}</MenuItem>
})}
```

You can read more about Lists and Keys rendering here:
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

In order to print user, since you are changing user on select change, after proper rendering MenuItems you should have that information inside user object and you should be able to render it like this.

```
{ user && <p>{user}</p> }
```

If you still need help, you need to add how data object looks like, in order for me to help you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Do you mean that I should create an interface with the model?

Comment: Well I didn't mean that, I meant you should update your question (provide more information in it about data object) 
But since you are asking about interface, if you are using  typescript you should use full power of it and you should add interface for both data, and props field, after that you will get nice intellisense in your component. You can do it like this: 
interface Props {
    data: IYourUserInterface
}

export const FormOne : React.FC<Props> = ({data}) => { ...component code here...